# How to change position of Div and return it back to previous position on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

hello guys i have two issues in my program.

The first issue is:

I have an `input` inside of it there is a `div` that include the word Title. What i want is when click on the `input` the `div` will go up. I managed to do this but if i clicked outside and there is nothing written in the `input` it won't go back to it's previous position. So to be clear if there was nothing written in the `input` box the `div` with title word should go back to their previous position and if there is something written in the `input` box it remain on top.

what I'm trying to achieve is similar to the one in this page <https://www.blogger.com/onboarding?pli=1#create

The second issue:
It is with the NEXT link (Next Button)
if i wrote on the `input` box and clicked next it will work and go to NEXT page

but if i did't write anything in the `input` box it will give an error message and won't go the NEXT page and i achieved that but the problem is after the error message if i try to write on the `input` box and click on the NEXT button it will not go to the NEXT page.

```js
function empty() {
    var x;
    var y;
            
    x = document.getElementById("counter-input").value;
    if (x == "") {
        y=document.getElementById("re").style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById("nxa").removeAttribute('href');
    }
        else
            {
                y=document.getElementById("re").style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById("nxa").getAttribute("href");
            
        
    }

        }
    var test = document.getElementById("test");

document.getElementById("counter-input").onclick = function() {
    
    
    test.style="font-size:12px; color: #2322EE;transform: translateY(-29px);visibility: visible!important;";
};
```

```css
    .sub2
    {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
padding: 16px;
min-height: 200px;
    }
    
    .ss
    
    {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
padding: 0 16px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
    }
    
    
.ss2
    
    {
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
display: inline-block;
outline: none;
width: 200px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
    }
    
    
.ss3
    
    {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
display: flex;
position: relative;
top: 14px;
    }
    
    
    .ss4
    {
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
display: flex;
    }
    
.cc
    {
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
pointer-events: none;
opacity: .3;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
flex: 1 1 auto;
font: 400 12px Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
min-height: 16px;
padding-top: 24px;
    
    }
    
    
.cc2{
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
flex: 1 1 auto;
font: 400 12px Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
min-height: 16px;
padding-top: 8px;
color: #ff5722;
display: none;
    }
    
    
    
.Xb
    {
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 1;
min-width: 0%;
position: relative;
    }
    
    
    
    
.whs
    {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
direction: ltr;
unicode-bidi: isolate;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 1;
background-color: transparent;
border: none;
display: block;
font: 400 16px Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
height: 24px;
line-height: 24px;
margin: 0;
min-width: 0%;
outline: none;
padding: 0;
z-index: 0;
    }
    
    
    .Ax
    {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
transform-origin: bottom left;
transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.2,1);
transition-property: color,bottom,transform;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.38);
font: 400 16px Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
pointer-events: none;
position: absolute;
bottom: 3px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
    }

    
    
    .i9
    {
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
bottom: -2px;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
background-color: #ff5722;
height: 1px;
    }

    
.Oab
    {
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
transform: scaleX(0);
bottom: -2px;
height: 2px;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
background-color: #ff5722;
        }
    
    
    .dv4
    {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
align-items: center;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
width: 100%;
    } 
    
    .dsk
    
    {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
transition: background .2s .1s;
border: 0;
border-radius: 3px;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 500;
outline: none;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
z-index: 0;
color: #ff5722;
line-height: 20px;
min-width: 88px;
    
    }
    
.ski
    {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 500;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #ff5722;
line-height: 20px;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
display: inline-block;
margin: 8px;
    }
    .dv6
    {
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
    }
    
a {text-decoration: none;}
    
.skip,.cancel,.next{color: #ff5722;}
    
    .sk,.cl,.nx
    {
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 500;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #ff5722;
line-height: 20px;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
position: relative;
    }
    
    .cldiv
    {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
transition: background .2s .1s;
border: 0;
border-radius: 3px;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 14px;
outline: none;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
z-index: 0;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
font-weight: 500;
line-height: 20px;
min-width: 88px;
    }
    
    
.nxdiv
    {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
transition: background .2s .1s;
border: 0;
border-radius: 3px;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 500;
outline: none;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
z-index: 0;
color: #ff5722;
line-height: 20px;
min-width: 88px;
    }
    
    
.req
    
    {visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
flex: 1 1 auto;
font: 400 12px Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
min-height: 16px;
padding-top: 8px;
color: #d50000;
        
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sub2">
            
        <div class="ss" >
    <div class="ss2">
    <div class="ss3">
        <div class="Xb">
            
            <input type="text" class="whs" tabindex="0" id="counter-input" maxlength="100" required>
            
            <div  class="Ax" id="test">Title</div>
        
        </div>
        
        
        
        <div class="i9"></div>
        <div  class="Oab" ></div>

    </div>


<div class="ss4">
    <div class="cc"><span class="req" id="re">Required feild must not be blank</span></div>
    <div class="cc2"></div>
  
    </div>

            </div>


            
        </div>
            
        <div class="dv4"> 
                
                    
                    <div class="dsk">
                    
                        <a href="" class="skip"><span class="sk"><span class="ski"><b>Prev</b></span></span></a></div>
                    

        <div class="dv6">
    <div class="cldiv">
        
        <a href="" class="cancel" style="align: left"><span class="cl"><span class="ski"><b>CANCEL</b></span></span></a></div>
    <div class="nxdiv" ><a href="Next.html" onClick="empty()" class="next" style="align: right" id="nxa"><span class="nx"><span class="ski"><b>NEXT</b></span></span></a></div>
            </div>
    </div>  
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue:

You need a class to attach to the "Title" div and toggle it based on whether the input is clicked and onblur. I've converted your "Title" div inline style into a class.

For the second issue:

You need to attach the href attribute back again after the user enter value into the input.

```js
function empty() {
  var counterInputValue = document.getElementById('counter-input').value; // Input value.
  var nextButton = document.getElementById('nxa'); // Next button.
  var errorMessage = document.getElementById('re'); // Error message.

  if (counterInputValue === '') { // When input is empty.
    errorMessage.style.visibility = 'visible'; // Display the error.
    if (nextButton.hasAttribute('href')) { // Remove the href attribute if it has it.
      nextButton.removeAttribute('href');
    }
  } else { // When error message is shown and input value present, we need to add the href back again.
    errorMessage.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    if (!nextButton.hasAttribute('href')) {
      nextButton.setAttribute('href', 'Next.html');
    }
  }
}

var test = document.getElementById('test');
var input = document.getElementById('counter-input');

input.onclick = function () {
  if(!test.classList.contains('test-div-on-click')) {
    test.classList.add('test-div-on-click');
  }
};

input.onblur = function () {
  if (input.value === '') {
    if(test.classList.contains('test-div-on-click')) {
      test.classList.remove('test-div-on-click');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.sub2 {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  text-align: start;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  padding: 16px;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.ss {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  text-align: start;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  padding: 0 16px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ss2 {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  text-align: start;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  width: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}

.ss3 {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  text-align: start;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  top: 14px;
}

.ss4 {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  text-align: start;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
}

.cc {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  text-align: start;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.3;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  font: 400 12px Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  min-height: 16px;
  padding-top: 24px;
}

.cc2 {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  text-align: start;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  font: 400 12px Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  min-height: 16px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  color: #ff5722;
  display: none;
}

.Xb {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  text-align: start;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  min-width: 0%;
  position: relative;
}

.whs {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  direction: ltr;
  unicode-bidi: isolate;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  font: 400 16px Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 0%;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.Ax {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  text-align: start;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition-property: color, bottom, transform;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
  font: 400 16px Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.i9 {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  text-align: start;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ff5722;
  height: 1px;
}

.Oab {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  text-align: start;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  bottom: -2px;
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ff5722;
}

.dv4 {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  text-align: start;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.dsk {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  transition: background 0.2s 0.1s;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  z-index: 0;
  color: #ff5722;
  line-height: 20px;
  min-width: 88px;
}

.ski {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ff5722;
  line-height: 20px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 8px;
}
.dv6 {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  text-align: start;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.skip,
.cancel,
.next {
  color: #ff5722;
}

.sk,
.cl,
.nx {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ff5722;
  line-height: 20px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
}

.cldiv {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  transition: background 0.2s 0.1s;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  z-index: 0;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 20px;
  min-width: 88px;
}

.nxdiv {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  transition: background 0.2s 0.1s;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  z-index: 0;
  color: #ff5722;
  line-height: 20px;
  min-width: 88px;
}

.req {
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  text-align: start;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  font: 400 12px Roboto, RobotoDraft, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  min-height: 16px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  color: #d50000;
}

.test-div-on-click {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #2322EE;
  transform: translateY(-29px);
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="sub2">
      <div class="ss">
        <div class="ss2">
          <div class="ss3">
            <div class="Xb">
              <input
                type="text"
                class="whs"
                tabindex="0"
                id="counter-input"
                maxlength="100"
                required
              />

              <div class="Ax" id="test">Title</div>
            </div>

            <div class="i9"></div>
            <div class="Oab"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="ss4">
            <div class="cc">
              <span class="req" id="re">Required feild must not be blank</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cc2"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="dv4">
        <div class="dsk">
          <a href="" class="skip"
            ><span class="sk"
              ><span class="ski"><b>Prev</b></span></span
            ></a
          >
        </div>

        <div class="dv6">
          <div class="cldiv">
            <a href="" class="cancel" style="align: left"
              ><span class="cl"
                ><span class="ski"><b>CANCEL</b></span></span
              ></a
            >
          </div>
          <div class="nxdiv">
            <a
              href="Next.html"
              onClick="empty()"
              class="next"
              style="align: right"
              id="nxa"
              ><span class="nx"
                ><span class="ski"><b>NEXT</b></span></span
              ></a
            >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the div when input is clicked or when it get focus and back to its normal position when input lose focus (blur). Additionally, you need to hide that div when input is not empty.

You can have better and easier control of what's happening by adding/removing CSS classes instead of attaching inline styles:

```js
var test = document.getElementById("test");
var counter = document.getElementById("counter-input");

function empty() {
    var x;
    var y;
            
    x = document.getElementById("counter-input").value;
    if (x == "") {
        y=document.getElementById("re").style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById("nxa").removeAttribute('href');

        // Empty input, show div
        test.classList.remove('not-show');
        // Does div must be above? if not, comment next line
        test.classList.add('show-up');
    } else {
        y=document.getElementById("re").style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById("nxa").getAttribute("href");
        // Ok, input has a value, hide the div
        test.classList.remove('show-up');
        test.classList.add('not-show');
    }
}
// Show the div, this function will be attached to 2 events
function moveTitle() {
  test.classList.remove('not-show');
  test.classList.add('show-up');
}

// Show div on input click or when it gets focused
counter.addEventListener('click', moveTitle);
counter.addEventListener('focus', moveTitle);

// Test contents when input lose focus
counter.addEventListener('blur', empty);
```

```css
.sub2
    {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
padding: 16px;
min-height: 200px;
    }
    
    .ss
    
    {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
padding: 0 16px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
    }
    
    
.ss2
    
    {
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
display: inline-block;
outline: none;
width: 200px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
    }
    
    
.ss3
    
    {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
display: flex;
position: relative;
top: 14px;
    }
    
    
    .ss4
    {
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
display: flex;
    }
    
.cc
    {
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
pointer-events: none;
opacity: .3;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
flex: 1 1 auto;
font: 400 12px Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
min-height: 16px;
padding-top: 24px;
    
    }
    
    
.cc2{
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
flex: 1 1 auto;
font: 400 12px Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
min-height: 16px;
padding-top: 8px;
color: #ff5722;
display: none;
    }
    
    
    
.Xb
    {
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 1;
min-width: 0%;
position: relative;
    }
    
    
    
    
.whs
    {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
direction: ltr;
unicode-bidi: isolate;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 1;
background-color: transparent;
border: none;
display: block;
font: 400 16px Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
height: 24px;
line-height: 24px;
margin: 0;
min-width: 0%;
outline: none;
padding: 0;
z-index: 0;
    }
    
    
    .Ax
    {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
transform-origin: bottom left;
transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.4,0,0.2,1);
transition-property: color,bottom,transform;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.38);
font: 400 16px Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
pointer-events: none;
position: absolute;
bottom: 3px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
    }

    
    
    .i9
    {
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
bottom: -2px;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
background-color: #ff5722;
height: 1px;
    }

    
.Oab
    {
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
transform: scaleX(0);
bottom: -2px;
height: 2px;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
background-color: #ff5722;
        }
    
    
    .dv4
    {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
align-items: center;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
width: 100%;
    } 
    
    .dsk
    
    {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
transition: background .2s .1s;
border: 0;
border-radius: 3px;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 500;
outline: none;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
z-index: 0;
color: #ff5722;
line-height: 20px;
min-width: 88px;
    
    }
    
.ski
    {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 500;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #ff5722;
line-height: 20px;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
display: inline-block;
margin: 8px;
    }
    .dv6
    {
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
    }
    
a {text-decoration: none;}
    
.skip,.cancel,.next{color: #ff5722;}
    
    .sk,.cl,.nx
    {
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 500;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #ff5722;
line-height: 20px;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
position: relative;
    }
    
    .cldiv
    {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
transition: background .2s .1s;
border: 0;
border-radius: 3px;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 14px;
outline: none;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
z-index: 0;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
font-weight: 500;
line-height: 20px;
min-width: 88px;
    }
    
    
.nxdiv
    {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-family: Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
transition: background .2s .1s;
border: 0;
border-radius: 3px;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 500;
outline: none;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
z-index: 0;
color: #ff5722;
line-height: 20px;
min-width: 88px;
    }
    
    
.req
    
    {visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
text-size-adjust: 100%;
text-align: start;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
flex: 1 1 auto;
font: 400 12px Roboto,RobotoDraft,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
min-height: 16px;
padding-top: 8px;
color: #d50000;
}
.show-up {
  font-size:12px;
  color: #2322EE;
  transform: translateY(-29px);
  visibility: visible!important;
}
.not-show {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sub2">
            
        <div class="ss" >
    <div class="ss2">
    <div class="ss3">
        <div class="Xb">
            
            <input type="text" class="whs" tabindex="0" id="counter-input" maxlength="100" required>
            
            <div  class="Ax" id="test">Title</div>
        
        </div>
        
        
        
        <div class="i9"></div>
        <div  class="Oab" ></div>

    </div>


<div class="ss4">
    <div class="cc"><span class="req" id="re">Required feild must not be blank</span></div>
    <div class="cc2"></div>
  
    </div>

            </div>


            
        </div>
            
        <div class="dv4"> 
                
                    
                    <div class="dsk">
                    
                        <a href="" class="skip"><span class="sk"><span class="ski"><b>Prev</b></span></span></a></div>
                    

        <div class="dv6">
    <div class="cldiv">
        
        <a href="" class="cancel" style="align: left"><span class="cl"><span class="ski"><b>CANCEL</b></span></span></a></div>
    <div class="nxdiv" ><a href="Next.html" onClick="empty()" class="next" style="align: right" id="nxa"><span class="nx"><span class="ski"><b>NEXT</b></span></span></a></div>
            </div>
    </div>  
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```